# can you send email notifications using the rally api?

Tags: rally

I am building a custom rally app, and I need to send out email notifications from it. Is there any way to send emails using the Rally API? so I don't have to use a third party service like Mandrill or Mailjet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this through the Rally API.