# Rally- Setup an email notification through the REST API

Tags: java, rest, email, rally

Is there a way to use Rally Rest API to setup an email notification for a user?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, this was recently answered by Rally's Kyle Morse on [can you send email notifications using the rally API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134936/can-you-send-email-notifications-using-the-rally-api)

Comment: I believe you are correct. However that is not the same question. That deals with sending emails though rally. I'm asking to setup notification rules for single user through the api.